# Controlling video playback speed during online video streaming in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am to play video in android from Vimeo doing online streaming. For this, Right now, I am using VideoView. Now, I wanna control the video playback speed control feature like: 0.5x,1x,1,5x,2x And video cache support. 
Are both of these possible with Android VideoView or is there any third player that I can use?
Help!

Comment: I want the same thing. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @MeghaManiar I did it by using Vimeo's open source video playback library.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for the best control i advice you with   [vlc lib](https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk) or [pvPlayer](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/2.0/external/opencore/doc/mio_developers_guide.pdf). or you can use this simple code but it dosen't work well.

```
public void slowMotion(){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (videoview != null) {

                if (videoview.isPlaying()){

                    videoview.pause();  
                }
                else{                        
                    videoview.start(); 
                }
            }

            handler.postDelayed(this, 50);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 800);        
}
```

Good luck :D